# creating an api to update postgres db with a json or yaml payload

Tags: python, django, api-design

I decided to ask this here after googling for hours. I want to create my own API endpoint on my own server.

Essentially I want to be able to just send a yaml payload to my server, when received I want to kick off my python scripts to parse the data and update the database. I'd also like to be able to retrieve data with a different call. I can code the back-end stuff, I just don't know how to make that bridge between hitting the server from outside and having the server do the things in the back-end in python.

Is django the right way? I've spent a couple days doing Django tutorials, really cool stuff, but I don't really need a website right now but whenever I search for web and python together, django pretty much always comes up. I don't need any python code help, just some direction on how to create that bridge.

Thanks.

Comment: i would suggest you take a look at [DRF](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) and probably [PyYAML](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation) for parsing the file

Comment: hey just reading up on DRF. I think its exactly the right direction .Thanks-

Comment: I also think DRF is what you're looking for. If you are looking for alternative, try Flask which is also a Python web framework which is much more light-weight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DRF was what I was looking for. As suggested.